# Using steganography on wavelet compressed image

Tags: java, cryptography, steganography

Can someone help in finding the source code for hiding an image(wavelet compressed image) with an image. I'm able to obtain source code only for hiding a text with an image.

Answer (score 3):

What about first encoding the wavelet compressed image as text (e.g. using [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)) and then hiding that? Pseudocode:

```
function steg_image_into_image( carrier_image, compressed_image )
{
    return steg_text_into_image( carrier_image, base64_encode(compressed_image) )
}
```

Comment: @anjana venkat, I'm glad it helped. In this case, could you please accept my answer, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask .